# Mapping Selenium Annotation to Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring, selenium

I am using Selenium to do some of my automation work. I am using Page Object Model(POM) based approach to define my WebElement property.

```
@FindBy(id = "username")
private WebElement usernameText;

@FindBy(css = "password")
private WebElement passwordText;
```

I do not want the annotation parameters(id=username and css=password) to be specified in the class directly.

Is it possible to move these to a bean properties file in Spring, so that I can map these annotations to a bean object.

For example, I can define a bean object to pass the id and css values, which should be auto-wired to this object in my Java class.

Comment: So you basically want to put found web element into application context, right? Could you provide an example how resulting Page Object class should look like?

Comment: @Anton : Yes, your understanding is correct. I don't have any end result in mind. I am just starting with Spring. I would be happy if we could achieve the solution is any possible way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually see how it may be useful for you making `WebElement` instance `ApplicationContext` aware as `WebElement` has no Spring beans dependencies. Despite it lets have a look what we will have to do to achieve the goal:

1. Each time `WebElement` is created by Selenium, `BeanDefinition` with `prototype` scope for this instance should be created as well and should be registered with a unique name in `BeanDefinitionRegistry`
2. After `BeanDefinition` is created, corresponding `WebElement` instance should be created lazily inside `ApplicationContext` as this `WebElement` may be absent in DOM in the moment of its creation. Additionally on this stage we have to provide locator somehow
3. As you will have a lot of `WebElement`s in a single Page Object, you will not be able to inject `WebElement` instance by type. Thus you will have to use `@Qualifier` or `@Resource` annotations on fields + `@Lazy` annotation for lazy bean initialization. It is at least 2 annotations on each `WebElement` field
4. ...

Do you see how complicated it is?

From my perspective you do not need to put `WebElement` into `ApplicationContext`. Some things that may be useful:

- In case Page Factory pattern usage implement `BeanPostProcessor` for your Page Objects and call `PageFactory.initElements(..)` from there. And that's it
- Get rid of `@FindBy` annotations and use Page Object pattern only. You can store your locators as `By` objects in `enum`. It is handy to store such `enum` as nested class of particular Page Object or as separate class if you wish so. You may retrieve these `By` objects using `WebElementFactory`.

Example below:

```
public interface Labeled {
    String label();
}

public interface ByAware {
    By locator();
}

public interface WebElementDescriptor extends ByAware, Labeled {
}

@Component("pageObject")
public class PageObject {

    @Autowired
    private WebElementFactory factory;

    public PageObject login(String name, String password) {
        factory.getWebElement(Element.USERNAME_FIELD).sendKeys(name);
        factory.getWebElement(Element.PASSWORD_FIELD).sendKeys(password);
        return this;
    }

    enum Element implements WebElementDescriptor {
        USERNAME_FIELD(By.id("username"), "User name input field"),
        PASSWORD_FIELD(By.cssSelector("password"), "Password input field");

        private By by;

        private String label;

        Element(By by, String label) {
            this.by = by;
            this.label = label;
        }

        @Override
        public String label() {
            return label;
        }

        @Override
        public By locator() {
            return by;
        }

    }

}

@Component("webElementFactory")
public class WebElementFactory {

    @Autowired
    private WebDriver driver;

    public WebElement getWebElement(WebElementDescriptor descriptor) {
        System.out.println("Processing " + descriptor.label());
        return driver.findElementBy(descriptor.locator());
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.. I understand how complex it is :) Is it possible to use a different custom annotation which can do the job which @findBy does?

Comment: @Purus yes, you can implement InstantiationAwareBeanPostProcessor for your Page Objects and inject found by WebDriver WebElements into it looking up for fields annotated with FindBy or with your custom annotation